# How to disable a JqueryUI Tab using HTML(not by code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

There is one way to disable a JQueryUI tab is -

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", 2);
```

But I want to disable it using HTML, like in JqueryUI 1.8, If we add '`ui-state-disabled`' class to the li, It will be disabled. Now even if I add this class, while creating the tab, JqueryUI ingnores it. Is there any other way this can be set through HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the way disabling the tabs have been changed.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", 2);  //Not working
```

The *last parameter tab index, should be given as array like*

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [2]);
```

After assinging as `ui-tabs`, make it as

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$("#tabs li:eq(1)").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

*1 - represents the tab-index.*

Whereas in html, you should not add this `class="ui-state-disabled"` in `li` instead add it in respective **`a`** tag like

```
<li>
  <a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-state-disabled" 
                       aria-disabled="true">Proin dolor</a>
</li>
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: yes, I know the first method. but if I add 'ui-state-disabled' to anchor, it gives flicker on li border top-bottom, code look flithy. Since JqueryUI also adds 'ui-state-disabled' class to li only, if we do it the code, is there any way that I can add it to li, & it works somehow!! Sorry for being so irrational.